# Determining a column name by column header in JTable

Tags: java, header, jtable

Is there any way to determine the column name by column header using Java `JTable` component? E.G., I could have column header like "Header" and column name "Column". And I'm looking for a method like Column_Name_From_Header("Header") -> "Column".

Comment: What do you mean by 'name'?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Comment: The example is in the first answer.
JTable tbl = ...
String colName = tbl.getModel().getColumnName(10);
But here is a ColumnName from integer value - column number.

Comment: no idea why you needed this value and whatever way, why do you need to know that,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate through the table columns of the table's column model. Find the one with the given header value (using `headerValue.equals(tableColumn.getHeaderValue()`). Then ask the `modelIndex` of the column (`tableColumn.getModelIndex()`), and ask the table's model for the column name at this index : `tableModel.getColumnName(index)`.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. I'm new to Java. Will try to implement this logic right now. I will post the results later.

Comment: Note that, as others, I wonder why you need such a thing. This probably indicates some misconception of your program.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a reference to a `JTable` then the easiest way to obtain the column name is to obtain it from the underlying `TableModel`; e.g.

```
JTable tbl = ...
String colName = tbl.getModel().getColumnName(10);
```

This is typically desirable as access is done using **model indices** rather than view indices.  This means, for example that if you resort the columns of your JTable the column names in the model will still have the same predictable order.

Comment: Well, yes. But in this example we have a getColumnName method that returns column name using an integer number as an input (e.g. 10). Not a string value of column header.

Comment: @Max: I don't quite follow - You have a String and you want to get back a String?  What is the header if not the column name?

Comment: Column header is what you see when the data is loaded into the table. When you look at the table in your program. E.g. "Apples". Column name is an internal variable name like "apples_1".

Comment: Which then raises the question.  Why do you (think you) need that information?

Comment: I'm trying to search through the table columns. And i need to exclude some of them out of the search set. But i don't want to hard - code by using static column indexes. That's why.

Comment: @Max: It sounds like your design is a bit odd - What is the purpose of the internal column name?  Why not just change this to be your display name rather than having to deal with the ugly situation of translating between two sets of Strings?

Comment: Thanks for advice, Adamski. I'll check what I can do with it.